# sass migrator problems - absolute paths and node_modules

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

Sorry for overloading this post, but my questions are (somewhat) releated.

**Absolute Paths**

I'm migrating a themed bootstrap app that uses absolute paths for all imports  (intellij has path settings for js, but not for sass and it automatically changes imports to absolute paths when refactoring scss files).

gulp-sass works fine with absolute paths.

But sass-migrator can't find imported partials and errors out:
Error: Could not find Sass file at 'src\theme\scss\variables-other'.

**Question** - Is there a path reference standard that I missed when I went to sass class and do I need to reset all my scss imports to use relative paths for imports?

**Node Modules**
I'm currently using bootstrap 5.0.1 (and other modules that are not compliant with the new sass standards).

It seems sass-migrator is attempting to "migrate" node modules, since I'm getting the above-mentioned path errors on bootstrap scss (and other node modules). I don't think this is kosher, since IMO the preferred way to remedy sass-compliance issues is to upgrade node mules directly (I'm in the process of updating bootstrap to 5.0.2, which is compliant).

**Question** - is there any flag to suppress migrating node modules? Or...is sass-migrator simply evaluating node modules so it can convert @import to @use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re question 01, sass-migrator only uses relative paths, so if you have a deeply nested hierarchy of partials, AFAIK you have to change all the absolute paths to relative ones. And no known fix for intellij resetting relative paths to absolute ones.

Re question 02, looks like sass-migrator only inspects node_modules.